# Convert raw SQL Query to Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is my current SQL Query.

```
'''UPDATE chat  SET recd="1"  WHERE nick_from="%s" AND nick_to="%s"
                           ''' % (sender_user, reciever_user)
```

I would like to convert it to Django ORM QuerySet.

The model is the following.

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    # id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nick_from = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nick_to = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField()
    sent = models.DateTimeField()
    recd = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.BigIntegerField()
    recd_email = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'chat'
```

Comment: How do you get results from an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Show your model definitions. Thanks.

Comment: i've added the model class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`QuerySet.filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and [`QuerySet.update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
chat.objects.filter(nick_from=sender_user, nick_to=receiver_user).update(recd='1')
```

Comment: @eddwinpaz, I don't get it. I gave you the answer. Doesn't it work?

Comment: it executes the Query but does not update the values to 1 and does not gives any errors

Comment: @eddwinpaz, Try to remove all the `try ... except ...`. It could hide the error occurred.

Comment: I did and stil not showing any errors, the Query gets executed but does not perform any changes on the Database.

Comment: @eddwinpaz, Could you put this after the `...update...` statement, and check what query executed? `from django.db import connection; print(connection.queries[-1]['sql'])`

Comment: this is the result UPDATE `chat` SET `recd` = 1 WHERE (`chat`.`nick_from` = 'eddwinpaz'  AND `chat`.`nick_to` = 'kudry' )

Comment: @eddwinpaz, How do you check that the records are not updated?

Comment: I tried the code yo gave me the following way chats =  chat.objects.filter(nick_from=sender_user, nick_to=receiver_user).update(recd='1') chats.save() is it right?

Comment: @eddwinpaz, No, just `chat.objects.filter(nick_from=sender_user, nick_to=receiver_user).update(recd='1')`

Comment: @eddwinpaz, `QuerySet.update` returns the count affected, not a model instance.

Comment: >>> from api.models import chat
>>> chat.objects.filter(nick_from='eddwinpaz', nick_to='kudry').update(recd='1')
37L
>>>

Comment: @eddwinpaz, `chat.objects.filter(nick_from='eddwinpaz', nick_to='kudry').values_list('recd', flat=True)` Try this in the shell. You will see that they are all `1`; which means they are updated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really pay attention to the ORM-specific shims, favouring raw SQL instead. In django, you can [easily do this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/):

```
chat.objects.raw(''''UPDATE chat  SET recd="1"  WHERE nick_from="%s" AND nick_to="%s"
                       ''' % (sender_user, reciever_user))
```

If this doesn't help, do leave a comment.

Comment: this is a old post but django ORM sucks so their Raw Wrapper.